# Removing a Content Security Policy in React is still active?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, security

I have a React Router app, and I need to have a content security policy just for one of the routes. So, for that route I have this inside a component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const csp = document.createElement('meta');
    csp.httpEquiv = "Content-Security-Policy";
    csp.content = "default-src 'none'; style-src embed.typeform.com; script-src 'self' embed.typeform.com; frame-src form.typeform.com";
    document.head.append(csp);
    return () => {
      document.head.removeChild(csp);
    }
  }, []);
```

My problem is that even though the code works, and the meta element is added and deleted as intended, Chrome doesn't remove the policy internally and it is always present once I have attached it once. So i get a lot of `default-src 'none'` errors on the other routes.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: `<meta>` elements don't work like CSS styles. Once the browser has seen the element, it's going to treat the page as if the policy property was in the HTTP header; it doesn't do any good to remove it.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how I can work around that limitation?

Comment: Maybe simply don't use that code on pages that you don't want it to affect?

Comment: CSP security headers reduce XSS risks and if you could change it from the Javascript side it would not make any sense. 

Comment: @n1md7 it totally makes sense if you change it from a script you trust initially.

Comment: If you could do that I think it would be a serious security flaw.

Comment: Depends on how you would think of the trusted scripts, as 'admins' or as just 'executors'.